# "John was happy about being accepted as a team member." What part of speech is "accepted"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, clauses, past-participles

> **John was happy about being accepted as a team member.**

In one sense, John is an accepted team member, so it could be an adjective.

In an other sense, John was accepted by someone, or by the team or coach. In this sense *being accepted* is a passive clause. But I suspect that the passive is not really established, because as a verb it still lacks attribution to an agent, and even if it did, John is the subject of the clause, the agent of the action is not.

(1) Parsing the sentence: *John was happy about something.*

**John was happy** about being accepted as a team member. S|V|SC(AJP+(pp):happy+(pp):accepted)

So in this parse, the SC is complex. The core SC (happy) is modified by the pp *about being accepted*, which is complex in itself because it takes a clause (copular verb + adjective) as an object, and *accepted* is also modified by another pp. Both of these pp are integral to the SC because they are tied to the core AJP *happy*; there is a chain of semantic dependency.

By *core* I mean any part of the sentence that is required in terms of syntax or meaning. If you remove a core part, the sentence breaks. The rest is just added, non-essential information.

So, in this parse *accepted* is an adjective.

(2) Parsing the sentence: *John was happy about something.*

In this parse the focus in on the clause *being accepted* where *being accepted* is taken by some as a passive construction, simply because it could take an agent attribution with the pp *by the coach*.

> John was happy about *being accepted by the coach* as a team member.

But if this is a passive form then it should have an equivalent active form as well, but it doesn't because *John* is the subject of the clause *being accepted*. So even with this attribution of agency the participle is still an adjective, or at least it is not a passive verb.

I would have to say that *accepted* is an adjective, by zero-derivation, but I'm not confident in that, given what a newbie I am.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by when you say the sentence has no "active form". Surely, "John was happy about the coach accepting him as a team member" would fit your criteria.

Comment: Does the sentence mean: John was happy about the ongoing state of being/feeling accepted or the (presumably) one-off event of being accepted into the team? It is similar to asking whether _disappointed_ is an adjective or a passive verb form in the sentence: _Jane dislikes being embarrassed_, i.e. in the state of feeling embarassment or embarrassed by some event?

Comment: @TimFoster - It does but you need to use the full form, with pronouns to get to it (e.g *him*). Aruacaria clarified this for me in her comments and answer below. Thanks.

Comment: @Shoe - This is a good point. It seems that both parses are valid. As John Lawler has called it - Schrödinger's participle. As you've pointed out - it may not be possible to definitively parse this as a bare sentence.

Comment: 'The window was broken' is perhaps the easiest example to see the two readings in. ',we noticed, when we arrived' / 'by the golf ball'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main types of passive, long passives and short passives:

> 1. Bob was arrested by the police. [long passive]
> 2. Bob was arrested. [short passive]

We can see from the examples above that a long passive is just a passive where the agent is described in a *by* preposition phrase appended to the end of the sentence. The short passive, in contrast, does not state who the agent is. In fact the very purpose of using a short passive is usually to efface the agent from the sentence. On his basis there is no reason not to regard *being accepted* as a non-finite passive clause, which is in fact what it probably is!

The Original Poster feels that their sentence cannot include a passive because an active voice version of the bracketed clause in (3) is not available:

> 3. John was happy about [(his) being accepted by the coach as a team member].

In fact, it is:

> 4. John was happy about  [the coach accepting him as a team member].

As an aside, however, it is a mistake to think that all passive sentences have an active counterpart. There are many English passives which have no active voice counterpart:

5. It is reputed to be the oldest hotel in Edinburgh.
6. *People repute it to be the oldest hotel in Edinburgh.

Note that in the same way that the subject of an active voice sentence is not aways an agent,  the NP in the *by* preposition phrase isn't always an agent either:

7. The actor is survived by his eldest son.

The *eldest son* in the sentence above is not an agent. They are not performing any action.

So, we have shown that it is clearly possible for the word *accepted* to be a verb forming part of a passive construction. However, as the Original Poster notes, there is also an adjective *accepted*. And as @Shoe notes in the comments under the question, there is another reading available, where John is happy about the state of acceptedness that he enjoys. We can do a test to see if an adjectival reading of '*accepted* is possible here.

To do this we need simply substitute the verb *BE* with the verb *BECOME*. The verb *BECOME* will take adjectives as complements but not participial verbs:

> 8. John was happy about becoming accepted as a team member [by the coach].

This seems to work, and so an adjectival reading is clearly also possible for the Original Poster's sentence.

Comment: Thanks. I think the interpretation of the short passive form depends largely on the verb used to form the participle and its applicability to the active subject (in the subject complement parse). No one says *arrested Bob*, but they might say *the arrested man*. Similarly with the sentence, *the car was damaged.* Without context it's impossible to say S|V|SC or S|Vp. Also, in the OP sentence we're talking about a nf clause, that is describing John, even with attribution, so I think there is a reason to think of this as not passive. In any case, I appreciate your thoughtful answer.

Comment: Also, if the long passive form is used then one should be able to reverse it to an active form. This can be done in your example - *His eldest son survives the actor.* The subject is the recipient of the action, which is fine. But this can't be done with *John's being accepted by the coach*. I wonder if there's a non-finite passive that could be reversed to an active form.

Comment: @UbuEnglish Well, the whole point of the short passive is tp delete the entity that would appear a the subject of the active version. Obviously when you reconstruct an acive voice sentence from a short passive, you need to reinsert the subject! I hadn't finished my post when you left your comments. Have a look now. What you think?

Comment: Excellent! How could forget about ellipsis? This is such a fundamental and clarifying concept - I feel stupid to not have seen it - I actually teach this from the very start, because when students can see ellipsis, it opens up the language for them. Ok, I see this now as a valid parse. Thanks, really. However, I still think parsing it as an adjective is equally valid. As a bare sentence it is not possible to know the intended meaning and either interpretation seems valid. See Shoe's comment on the OP. What do you think?

Comment: 'You do not need to worry about being happy as a team member' shows that an adjective is possible here. But in OP's example, the 'as a team member' virtually forces the verbal interpretation on 'accepted'. // What semantic role would you ascribe to 'his eldest son' in 'His eldest son survived him'?

Comment: @UbuEnglish I agree and have updated.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not very good on thematic roles (understatement), but might it be a *theme*?

Comment: The list of semantic roles at [elies.rediris.es](http://elies.rediris.es/elies11/cap5111.htm) gives a list of definitions and then examples which do not seem to match up. 'Theme' seems to demand an action verb. 'Experiencer' or 'patient' might work (the requirement for 'psychological experiencing' isn't mentioned in the 'definition'. With 'His eldest son succeeded him', it becomes even more problematic as there's now a benefactive element.

Comment: Araucaria - "4. John was happy about [the coach accepting him as a team member]." Shouldn't the verb form be [the coach *having accepted* him...] just to be consistent with the participle form, or am I off the rails again?

Comment: @UbuEnglish They're both good :)

Comment: There is another way of seeing it which I think pushes hard in favor of it being an adjective. The semantic chain starts with Tim, *happy Tim*, and goes from *happy* to *about being accepted* - *happy accepted Tim* - and even if the nf-clause takes the by an agent attribution, the whole cluster is still describing Tim. I definitely fall on the side of parsing this as an adjective. The passive perfect participle form is adjectival. It is said that English doesn't have a passive perfect participle, but there it is.

Answer (score 2):

//John was happy about being accepted as a team member.//

ACCEPTED is a past participle verb. Here,"being accepted" is the passive voice of "accepting"
Its is like, 
happy at being honoured (Someone is honouring), or
happy at being received (Someone is receiving)

Comment: It's more complicated than that - please read the comment threads.